# Laravel Nested Query in Many to Many Relationship from within Blade Template

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, php-7

I'm trying to isolate different team members based on their roles, filtering them within a blade view's $teams as $team @foreach loop.  The output would be a simple list of the team members with the given role.  I've been scouring the net for clues on this for several days, and I'm sure the answer is right in front of me - I'm just not seeing it yet.  Ideally, I would love to be able to have the api flow logically, e.g. something like the following:

`$team->user->role('manager')`

The relations between Team, User, and Role classes are all many-to-many

Team.php

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

User.php

```
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_user', 'user_id', 'team_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Role.php

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Admin/TeamsController.php

```
    public function index()
    {
        $teams = Team::with('users')->orderBy('location', 'asc')->paginate(10);

        return view('admin.teams.index')->with([
            'teams' => $teams,
        ]);
    }
```

So what does one have to do to load up multiple relationships like these in order to isolate the roles of each member of a given team within the blade view?

---

Edit to show final solution (with strong input from @wschopohl below):

In Team.php class:

```
    public function userWithRole($role)
    {
        return $this->users()->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($role) {
            $query->where('name', $role);
        })->with('roles')->get();
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($teams as $team)
    <tr>
        <td class="px-4 py-2 border">{{ $team->location }}</td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2 border">
            @foreach ($team->userWithRole('lead') as $user)
                <li style="list-style: none;">{{ $user->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2 border">
            @foreach ($team->userWithRole('manager') as $user)
                <li style="list-style: none;">{{ $user->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2 border">
            @foreach ($team->userWithRole('somethingelse') as $user)
                <li style="list-style: none;">{{ $user->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than I assumed.

The best thing I can come up with right now is this:

```
$users = $team->users()->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'manager');
})->get();
```

This is ugly to use in a blade template, of course. That's why I would use a method like this on the `Team` Model

```
public function usersWithRole($role) {
    return $this->users()->whereHas('roles', function($query) use($role) {
        $query->where('name', $role);
    })->with('roles')->get();
}
```

So now in your blade template you can do:

```
@foreach($team->usersWithRole('manager') as $user)
```

Comment: Your assumption is right (roles table column is called 'name'), but this line (which I've tried numerous times before) produces:
`undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::roles()`

It doesn't appear that eloquent is moving through the Team relationship with User all the way to Role.  This is the part that's had me banging my head against dead-ends for nearly a week.

Comment: Try updated answer, Im sorry i cant test myself right now

Comment: No need for sorry.  I deeply appreciate your input here!
This seems like a bit of progress, as I'm now getting:
`Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Comment: I just noticed the ->get() at the end of your suggestion.  When I added that, it blew up with:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `team_user`.`team_id` as `pivot_team_id`, `team_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `team_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `team_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `users` inner join `team_user` on `users`.`id` = `team_user`.`user_id` where `team_user`.`team_id` = 10 and `roles`.`name` = manager and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)`

It doesn't appear to be probing the roles table at all.

Comment: just a stupid side question: All your relationships are working, if you query them one by one, right?

Comment: I keep coming back to wondering if I need to somehow include the user roles in my TeamsController.  Is it possible to with() on a with()?

Comment: I think you chain "with" with dots, like this with('users.roles') ..

Comment: Well, it's quite fugly, but Bingo! (with a slight adjustment).
Thanks a ton for your exceptional patience!

```
@foreach ($teams as $team)
 <tr>
  <td class="px-4 py-2 border">
   @foreach ($team->users()->whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'poc');
    })->get() as $user)
     <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
   @endforeach
  </td>
  ...
 </tr>
```

Please adjust your post to reflect what worked, so others might discover it and save themselves some hair loss.   :D

Comment: last update, this is the best I can come up with right now :D

Comment: The slight adjustment was just to run it within the blade view, so
`(... as $user)`

The added method and blade code is now working perfectly, as shown at the bottom of the edited post above.  Thanks again for saving what's left of my sanity!